# Delete Alert confirmation on Tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I wanna have an alert confirmation when I'm swipe and click on the delete button on a tableview.
Basically I wanna show an alert pop-up with "ok" and "cancel" button before sending data with :

```
[[ConnectionSingleton getInstance] sendData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"modifOrderFoodState::%@::%@::%@", [cellOrder objectForKey:@"orderFoodRelId"], state, [ConnectionSingleton getInstance].restaurantId] ];
```

and if the client click on the cancel button, abord the sending data function.

This is my code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSMutableDictionary *cellOrder = [orders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *state = @"4";

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {


    [[ConnectionSingleton getInstance] sendData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"modifOrderFoodState::%@::%@::%@",
                                                 [cellOrder objectForKey:@"orderFoodRelId"],
                                                 state,
                                                 [ConnectionSingleton getInstance].restaurantId] ];
  }    
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this class a UIAlertViewDelegate.  Create a UIAlertView when the style is delete.  Move the send data code into the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method and run it if the user clicked OK.

Comment: Thanks that's working, but I got a problem with the index.path.row element i got before.
How to get the current row index ?

Comment: You can either save the row as a property in your object or maybe make cellOrder a property and then show the alert.  (Or call indexPathForSelectedRow on the table view.)